# Numeric Solution of a Patial Differential Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Hiiii,

I have a system which is discribed by eight coupling PDEs and with a long simulation time. Some of these PDEs have the following form and I wanted to know what is the best **numerical** method to solve them:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = -\alpha\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}+g(z,t)$$
where $g(z,t)$ is a numerical function.

Bests,

Reza